# Can't this be rewritten more concisely using fluent syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public static class ListOfT
{

    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this List<T> value, 
                                                       Func<T, string> getText, 
                                                       Func<T, string> getValue, 
                                                       string selectedValue)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = getText(item),
                Value = getValue(item),
                Selected = selectedValue == getValue(item) 
            });
        }

        return items
            .OrderBy(l => l.Text)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{

    List<State> states = new List<State>() { new State {Name = "Michigan", StateCode = "MI" },
                                             new State {Name = "Connecticut", StateCode = "CT" }};

    StateAssessmentCreateViewModel stateAssessmentViewModel = new StateAssessmentCreateViewModel();
    stateAssessmentViewModel.States = states.ToSelectList(state => state.Name, state => state.StateCode, "CT"); 

    return View(stateAssessmentViewModel);
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode, Model.States, "-- None -- ", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I think my syntax in the view is wrong because the formcontrol class attribute isn't properly formatted. Note sure why, though.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="StateCode">State</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <select htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="StateCode" name="StateCode"><option value="">-- None -- </option>
                                        <option selected="selected" value="CT">Connecticut</option>
                                    <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
                        </select>
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="CancelDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
.
```

Comment: Do you mean LINQ syntax?

Comment: So what's the programming problem you have? If you have working code you just want rewritten, we have [CodeReview.SE] for that. If you have an actual problem, it needs to be written in such a way that it'll be helpful to others. "Can this be rewritten more concisely using fluent syntax" will never be a useful term for others to see if they have the same problem you do.  We also need more than just a dump of your code.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker In it's current state, it would be off-topic anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have project with `Select` :

```
public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this List<T> source,
                                                   Func<T, string> getText,
                                                   Func<T, string> getValue,
                                                   string selectedValue)
{
    return source
        .Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = getText(x),
            Value = getValue(x),
            Selected = selectedValue == getValue(x)
        })
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. After posting, I decided to also mention an actual problem that I was having with the class not appearing correct in the "View Source" markup, but the post title didn't reflect that and the Powermaniac Moderators went to town on it in seconds...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean by :  the class not appearing correct in the "View Source" markup

Comment: BTW, you should open a new question if you have another one, as this one is losing traffic. Just take some time to formulate it nicely.

Comment: I changed the code to this: @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateCode, Model.States, "-- None -- ", new { @class = "form-control" }) and it worked. Note that my original post had the wrong razor code. I meant to post the line that created a dropdown. It has been corrected,